# How to save a bitmapimge from url to an object of bitmap in wp8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want to save am image from `[URL : https://www.example.com/folders/file.jpg][1]` 
in an object of BitmapImage

I tried the following `:`

```
BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
b.SetSource(new Uri("https:www.example.com/folders/file.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

But its not working. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? Any exception or error message? Be more specific please.

Comment: Actuall my foolish ness b.SetSource() takes stream as argument   ....an i was trying to pass an Uri through it  natuarally it wont take ...... but i got new problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code test and work for me:
    Image MyImage = new Image();

```
        // Create source.
        BitmapImage bImage = new BitmapImage();
        bImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"https:www.example.com/folders/file.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        // Set the image source.
        MyImage.Source = bImage;
```

Tell me if work for you or need more info. Good luck man!